# How do I test the sequence of values of a column (based on timestamps) within each group in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, amazon-redshift, sql-timestamp

I have colA, colB, colC in tableA where colC is a timestamp variable.

there are 5 possible values for colB.

```
select distinct(colB) from tableA; 

x
y
z
```

I want to make sure that for each value of colA, the record(s) with colB='a' has earlier timestamps than record(s) with colB='b' and so on. So, colB='b' records should come after colB='a' and colB='c' records should come after colB='b' for each value of colA

I need a SQL query for the same

Comment: why don't you better write some example data? The unique example I see is where you say that there are 5 possible values for colB, with just 3 different values x, y, z. So difficult to help with this information.

Comment: Also see [mcve].

Comment: And what do you want the results to look like?

Comment: correctly pointed out. That's a mistake. I made up the query and the scenario. I couldn't share the actual data which made me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select cola
from tableA
group by cola
having max(case when colb = 'a' then timestamp end) < min(case when colb = 'b' then timestamp end) and
       max(case when colb = 'b' then timestamp end) < min(case when colb = 'c' then timestamp end) and
      . . .
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted